# How to SET a table with IGNORE_DUP_KEY on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am studying and I found this situation, on SQL we can ignore them `IGNORE_DUP_KEY=OFF` but on PostgreSQL
that instruction does not exist

Is there any way to replicate this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: If I am following correctly then [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)  with [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) should do something similar.

Comment: I guess you are mixing up SQL and Microsoft SQL Server. Care to explain what this setting is supposed to do?

Comment: @Adrian_Klaver ON CONFLICT is not an option of indexes. It is a pseudo SQL specfic clause for DML on INSERT statement in PostGreSQL... So I maintain that there is no equivalent of  "IGNORE_DUP_KEY" in PostGreSQL despite the fact that you give me negative notes ! If you want to use the PG ON CONFLICT you must modify all your queries that INSERTs data !

Answer (score -3):

If the SQL langage is quite similar over mainly all RDBMS, all the command that are at the physical level, like those about INDEX and STORAGE are very different because each editors have its own wway to do it with some specific functionalities...

By the way, there is no equivalent of IGNORE_DUP_KEY in PostGreSQL indexes...

You have to do it in the DML